# How to solve 'dynamic module does not define module export function' error in Xcode kivy-ios?

Tags: ios, python-3.x, firebase, kivy, pycrypto

I am trying to package a python app in iOS. The app is very simple with just 1 line:

```
from firebase import firebase
```

I follow the instruction from this link:

```
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
```

Firebase would need pycrypto. So I typed

```
./toolchain.py build pycrypto
```

and it failed... So I copied and pasted 3 folders: Crypto, cryptography, cryptography-2.7.dist-info from folder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages to the build folder under Desktop/kivy-ios. Then I typed:

```
./toolchain.py build pycrypto
```

and it still failed... So instead of that, I used:

```
./toolchain.py pip install pycrypto
```

It succeeded! I went into Xcode and tried to push it to a virtual iPhone XR. I got the following error which I have no idea how to resolve. Please help me out! Anything is greatly appreciated.

```
2019-09-13 01:24:40.859097-0400 kindact[56329:305598] [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
2019-09-13 01:24:41.060178-0400 kindact[56329:305598] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=LandscapeLeft LandscapeRight Portrait PortraitUpsideDown
2019-09-13 01:24:41.060467-0400 kindact[56329:305598] Initializing python
/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/kindact:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
2019-09-13 01:24:41.255757-0400 kindact[56329:305598] Running main.py: /Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/YourApp/main.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 39, in load_module
  File "/Users/hiencao/Desktop/2/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cryptography_hazmat_bindings__constant_time)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 39, in load_module
  File "/Users/hiencao/Desktop/2/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cryptography_hazmat_bindings__constant_time)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hiencao/Desktop/2/kivy-ios/kindact-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import python_jwt as jwt
  File "/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_jwt/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jwcrypto.jws import JWS, JWSHeaderRegistry
  File "/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwcrypto/jws.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jwcrypto.jwa import JWA
  File "/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwcrypto/jwa.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, hashes, hmac
  File "/Users/hiencao/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E046BFB-CB75-4394-BBBB-CD52178F0DEA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C9C66E4B-7DBA-409C-88FA-F0917B4D6681/kindact.app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
  File "<string>", line 43, in load_module
  File "/Users/hiencao/Desktop/2/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__constant_time)
2019-09-13 01:24:42.146234-0400 kindact[56329:305598] Application quit abnormally!
2019-09-13 01:24:42.165161-0400 kindact[56329:305598] Leaving
```

Comment: When you say "Firebase would need pycrypto." why is that the case? It looks like the firebase module is just an easy way to perform some standard REST requests, which you should be able to use without using the `firebase` module if it requires pycrypto

Comment: I use firebase module to post and get data from the Firebase Realtime Database. I executed the main.py (from firebase import firebase) in pycharm and it wouldn't run without pycrypto. It's like this: ```from firebase import firebase
FBConn = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://python-app-4857e.firebaseio.com/', None)
c = FBConn.get('/MyUsersEmail', None)
print(c)

Comment: If pycrypto is the issue and you are using it to get and post data from Firebase Realtime database, I would say just stop using the `firebase` module altogether. You can achieve the same functionality without the `firebase` module, and thus without pycrypto as well :) I have some videos on working with firebase without the firebase module! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgpoQZN9G6M

Comment: As you suggested, I replace Firebase by requests and json. Now I can post and get from Firebase Realtime Database without the use of firebase and pycrypto which has been very problematic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Firebase module by Requests and json modules.

Comment: Also, you can use the UrlRequest class that is included with Kivy if you want to make requests without blocking your main thread. You might notice using the `requests` package that your application is freezing while it's sending/retrieving data. The UrlRequest class does this asynchronously for you and is super easy to use! Tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nI9mjajX4TI

Comment: Ah no wonder the progressspinner always froze when I sent data. UrlRequest works flawlessly on pc. However, on mobile, I needed to do the following to make it work: ````import certifi as cfi        UrlRequest(signup_url, req_body=signup_payload,
                   on_success=self.successful_login,
                   on_failure=self.sign_up_failure,
                   on_error=self.sign_up_error,ca_file=cfi.where(), verify=True)